# General formula for a summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I can't find the general formula for the following sum.

$q \in \Bbb R, q \ne 1$

$\sum _{i=0}^{n} q^{2i}$

Any hints?

Comment: Hint: Finite geometric series. The formula will not work when $q=\pm 1$.

Comment: Indeed. I forgot to clarify q is a real and not equaling 1. I'll check into your hint, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. You should end up with $\frac{1-q^{2n+2}}{1-q^2}$ (or if you prefer, multiply top and bottom by $-1$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a geometric series with ratio $q^2$.
If $q=\pm1$, then
$$\sum_{i=0}^n q^{2i}=n+1$$
Otherwise,
$$\sum_{i=0}^n q^{2i}=\frac{1-q^{2(n+1)}}{1-q^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

In general, $\sum_{i=a}^{\infty}r^n=\dfrac{r^a}{1-r}$, for $|r|<1$. So
$$\frac{1}{1-q^2}?$$